# Run a motion command (like yy) in an eval expression in vim?

Tags: vim, eval

Is it possible to run a motion command inside an eval expression in vim? I want to use it in [snipmate](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim/blob/master/autoload/snipMate.vim#L70).

For example, in command mode:

```
:call eval('yy')
```

It shows `E121: undefined variable 'yy'`. I would like to call these commands as motion ones. I've searched a bit `:help functions` but couldn't find anything to help me.

Comment: Can you provide more information about «plugin that receives a parameter»? It is possible to define user mapping which takes a motion (see examples under `:h g@`), but without knowledge about what this plugin expects to receive nothing can be suggested.

Comment: @ZyX: I added the plugin I'm using. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are looking for `exe "normal! yy"`.
`eval()` is meant to evaluate expressions (:h expr ...)

EDIT:
In summary, What you can try in your case:

- have a function that do what you what to do: move (which I'd advice you against), yank, fetch information from the context
- have the function return an empty string
- and use that function with snipMate (which I can't help you with)

Comment: @Luc Hermitte: I would like to use eval, there's a plugin that receives a parameter and uses eval in it and I would like to do these motion commands. I thought eval was used to evaluate any VimL command...

Comment: The important question is: what does this plugin do with the evaluated expression? Depending on the answer, there may be a way to return a movement. Otherwise, you can always call a neutral function (regarding what is evaluated) that moves the cursor. May I ask which plugin are to trying to interact with ?

Comment: @Luc Hermitte: Snipmate. The snippets file can have vim expressions that are evaluated by eval(), in autoload/snipMate.vim. https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim/blob/master/autoload/snipMate.vim#L70

Comment: As the maintainer of another templates-expander plugin, my guess is that you should avoid motion commands from your snippets. With mu-template, I use `getline('.')+search(xxx,'n') to search things in the current context, and its API to access the lines from the template. Back to snipMate, the code suggests me that you may be  able to use functions that return an empty string.

Comment: @Luc Hermitte: Your last edit was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for answering and helping. (This is not pretty, calling a function inside snipmate, but it works and keeps all my snippets in *.snippets files from snipmate instead of a lot of functions in vimrc or in separate modules.)

Comment: With mu-template I often have either external functions or embedded functions in order to support non-trivial computations (cycling through the values of an enum to generate all the cases of a switch statement; choosing the semantics of a C++ class, fetching the qualified name of the current class, etc). Sometimes having functions is the best choice for our snippets/wizards.